# Grammatical case of 'sich niederlassen auf + obj.'

Tags: grammatical-case

Good day, I am quite new to German. What would be the correct way to say:

> They settle down in the seat.

Is it

> Sie lassen auf den Sessel nieder.

or

> Sie lassen auf dem Sessel nieder.

Moreover, is there a comprehensive reference where I can find what prepositions and object cases that are used with a certain verb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct translation would be neither of yours, but

> > Sie lassen **sich** auf dem Sessel nieder.

Using *sich* is mandatory, the form of the verb *niederlassen* implies that.

> > Sie lassen **sich** auf **den** Sessel nieder.

Would be fine as well, but carries a bit different emphasis regarding *den Sessel* as direction of the movement.

---

> Moreover, is there a comprehensive reference where I can find what prepositions and object cases that are used with a certain verb?

Sure, there are many references like e.g. [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/niederlassen) you can use for research.

Comment: Yes, I totally forgot about 'sich'. What do you mean that 'the form implies'? What is 'the form'?

Comment: @Atin The form is _**sich** niederlassen_.